# websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 400

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, header

I can't connect to a websocket using [`websockets` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets). I have the following code:

```
import asyncio, ssl
import websockets


headers= {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'Upgrade',
        'Host': ...,
        'Origin': ...,
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Upgrade': 'websocket',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'
    }

async def hello():
    uri = ...
    async with websockets.connect(ssl=0,
                                  extra_headers=headers,
                                  origin="*",
                                  uri = uri) as websocket:
        pass

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AFMN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\kr ws.py", line 30, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
  File "C:\Users\AFMN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\AFMN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\kr ws.py", line 19, in hello
    async with websockets.connect(ssl=0,
  File "C:\Users\AFMN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 517, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "C:\Users\AFMN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 542, in __await_impl__
    await protocol.handshake(
  File "C:\Users\AFMN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 296, in handshake
    raise InvalidStatusCode(status_code)
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 400
```

But the issue is, I can connect to the websocket using [`websocket` module](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/), but I don't want to use it due to several reasons. But if it helps, here is the code using `websocket`:

```
import websocket, ssl
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time, msgpack

headers= {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'Upgrade',
        'Host': ...,
        'Origin': ...,
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Upgrade': 'websocket',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'
    }

def on_message(ws, message):
    ...

def on_error(ws, error):
    ...

def on_close(ws):
    ...

def on_open(ws):
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(...,
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close,
                              header=headers,
                              subprotocols=["binary", "base64"])
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
```

Why can't I connect to the websocket in the first code, while I can connect to same websocket using the other module?

How do I connect using the first one?

Comment: Ok, I think I have an idea: maybe your payload was too big?

Answer (score 1):

When calling the `wobsockets.connect`, instead of passing `ssl=0`, set a TLS protocol. It can be set using the Python `ssl` package using `ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)`. So your connection should change as bellow:

```
    async with websockets.connect(ssl=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS),
                                  extra_headers=headers,
                                  origin="*",
                                  uri = uri) as websocket:
        pass
```

Comment: this worked for me - thanks. Why doesn't it default to TLS protocol? and why does the original SSL error happen?

Answer (score 0):

What is your URL? It looks like that server only support websockets over TLS, so you should use `wss://` rather than `ws://`